# Qt: I defined and registered a QML singleton in C++. How do I access this singleton from C++?

Tags: c++, qt, singleton, qml

I had no problems with defining and registering a QML singleton in C++, and using that singleton from QML. Now, however, I want to call methods on that singleton from C++ as well. How do I get access to the single instance that the singleton has?

For now I've done the following hack:

```
FileIO* fileIO;

static QObject* fileIOSingletonTypeProvider(QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine) {
    Q_UNUSED(engine)
    Q_UNUSED(scriptEngine)

    FileIO* instantiatedObj = new FileIO();
    ::fileIO = instantiatedObj;
    return instantiatedObj;
}

// ...

qmlRegisterSingletonType<FileIO>("FileIO", 1, 0, "FileIO", fileIOSingletonTypeProvider);
```

So I store a global pointer to it at the point of instantiation.

This works. Is there a proper way to do it, though?

Comment: You can invoke a QML function that returns a reference to it and store it in a pointer on the C++ side.

Comment: That's no better than my technique though.

Comment: Well, accessing QML stuff from C++ is generally considered counter-productive and indicative of bad design.

Comment: @ddriver: There's nothing inherently "QML" about my singleton, the only reason it's a QML singleton instead of a normal C++ class with static functions (or similar) is so I can access it from QML. That doesn't mean the functionality it provides is not also useful for usage from C++. It's useful for usage from both QML and C++.

Comment: The question is basically "how to access C++ objects from C++" which is... d'oh :)

Comment: If you want to make something available in QML which you want to control from C++ you might be better off using `qmlEngine->rootContext()->setContextProperty(name, obj)`

Comment: QML singleton is not per-program but per-engine. So to make the code clear, I'd make a real C++ singleton and a wrapper class that is instantiated as a QML singleton.